# Digitize by User Input by Distance and Length in QGIS

Tags: qgis, editing

I was wondering if anyone knows a way to digitize a line or polygon by user entered distance and length.  This is an option in ArcMap, but I would like to be able to do this in QGIS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a plugin called 'Azimuth and Distance' in QGIS. That will allow you to create line or polygon based on distance and angle.